# Get contents of <body> </body> within a string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to do the following.

```
$("a").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {

        $("html").html(data);

    });

});
```

I want the behavior of all hyperlinks to make a ajax calls and retrieve the html.

Unfortunately you cannot simply replace the current html with the html you receive in the ajax response.

How can grab only what is within the `<body> </body>` tags of the ajax response so that i can replace **only** the contents of the body in the existing html.

Edit: the `<body>` opening tag will not always be just `<body>` it may sometimes have a class e.g.

`<body class="class1 class2">`

Comment: what's wrong with `$("body").html()` ?

Comment: Why would you like to Replace all the contents of the BODY? **PUN INTENDED**

Comment: The best answer I've found for this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628374/how-to-extract-body-contents-using-regexp/3642850#3642850

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, grab the content between the body tags with a regex.

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
    var body=data.replace(/^.*?<body>(.*?)<\/body>.*?$/s,"$1");
    $("body").html(body);

});
```

EDIT

Based on your comments below, here's an update to match any body tag, irrespective of its attributes:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
    var body=data.replace(/^.*?<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>.*?$/i,"$1");
    $("body").html(body);

});
```

The regex is:

```
^               match starting at beginning of string

.*?             ignore zero or more characters (non-greedy)

<body[^>]*>     match literal '<body' 
                    followed by zero or more chars other than '>'
                    followed by literal '>'

(               start capture

  .*?           zero or more characters (non-greedy)

)               end capture

<\/body>        match literal '</body>'

.*?             ignore zero or more characters (non-greedy)

$               to end of string
```

Add the 'i' switch to match upper and lowercase.

And please ignore my comment regarding the 's' switch, in JavaScript all RegExp are already single-line by default, to match a multiline pattern, you add 'm'. (Damn you Perl, interfering with me when I'm writing about JavaScript! :-)

Comment: I don't think that regex works, i did a console.log on the body variable and it was still returning all of the html, not just what was within the body tags.

Comment: Running the following code: var page='<html><head><title>foo</title></head><body>body</body></html>';
page.replace(/^.*?<body>(.*?)<\/body>.*?$/, "$1");
provides: 'body' as its answer.

Comment: Ahh...forgot to mention, for multi-line content, you'll need to add the 's' flag to the regex to treat the entire string as a single line. (Example has been edited.)

Comment: With the edited regex im getting 'SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s' in firebug

Comment: I forgot to mention, the `<body>` tag will not always be just `<body>` it will sometimes have a class, `<body class="class1 class2">` would it be possible for you to update the regex to accommodate for this?

Comment: wow, thanks for detailed reply rob, unfortunately i still cannot get it to work. if you change `$("body").html(body);` in your script to `console.log (body);` then run the script in firebug on this particular stackoverflow page and click a hyperlink somewhere, you'll see that it's still returning the whole page from `<html>` to `</html>`

Comment: `$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
    var body=data.replace(/^.*?<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>.*?$/i,"$1");
    console.log (body);
})`

Comment: @RobRaisch I don't see the point of the backslash in the closing body tag. There's no need to escape the following slash, is there?

Comment: If I understand your question, since the RegExp is delimited by slashes, it is critical to escape any slashes contained within it. To do otherwise would cause the JavaScript parser to croak.

Comment: how do I modify this to select multiple parts of the html ? suppose from the html content, I need the content inside <head></head> followed by the content inside <body></body>

Comment: Keep in mind the dangers of the famous [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer (currently with 4426 upvotes).

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch Indeed, but there is a profound difference between extracting the contents of clearing delimited, non-repeating containers like `<head/>` or `<body/>`, and attempting extract deeply-nested content. Regexen are a perfect solution for the former and as has been noted many times, inappropriate for the later.

Comment: @RobRaisch I upvoted your comment because it has merrit. However my claim still stands: Regexes are not up for the job. A `<body>` can contain a `<script>` tag with a `// </body>` comment. That is valid in HTML5 but will break the regex above. While a regex may work on some (or most) HTML, regexes  are unable to do this reliably for all valid HTML `<body>` tags, and so I was looking for something more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to mess with regular expressions. Instead, I created a hidden `<iframe>`, loaded the contents in it, and extracted the `<body>` from the page in the `<iframe>` in the page's `onload()`.

I needed to be careful with [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for the the iframe (this [article](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/) showed the way):

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
jQuery('body').append(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.contents = data;
iframe.onload = function () {
    var bodyHTML = jQuery(iframe).contents()
                        .find('body').html();
    // Use the bodyHTML as you see fit
    jQuery('#error').html(bodyHTML);
}
iframe.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
```

Just remove the `<iframe>` when you're done...

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to bind events to the document, filtered by class (`$(document).on('click', '.my-class-name', doThings);`) If you replace the html of the body, any event bindings done directly (`$('.my-class-name').on('click', doThings);`) will be destroyed when DOM is redrawn using the new html. Rebinding will work, but it will also leave a bunch of pointers from the old events and nodes that the garbage collector will have to clean up -- in simpler terms it may make the page get heavier and heavier the longer it is open.

I have not tested this on multiple platforms, use with caution.

```
// create a new html document
function createDocument(html) {
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('')
  doc.documentElement.innerHTML = html
  return doc;
}
$("a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
        $("body").html($(createDocument(data)).find('body').html);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would've loved for this to work. But `jQuery('<html><body>foobar</body></html>').find('body').length == 0` :-( For that reason I'm downvoting.

Comment: Weirdly, `jQuery('<div><span>foobar</span></div>').find('span').length == 1`, but I can't extract a `<body>` from a `<html>`

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch I added a function there to make a new html document first. This seems to work -- can you confirm?