# removing html, head, body tag inside TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to get only the content of the body element in TinyMce in my project and then inject that part inside another page.
when I submit my textarea to my controller the content of tinymce does have  ,  and  html tag.

how to get rid of them ? is there any built in functionality inside TinyMce for doing this ?

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*tinymce definition*/
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea.tinymce",
            theme: "modern",
            height: 10,
            plugins: [
                 "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker example fullpage",
                 "searchreplace visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                 "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor wordcount"
           ],
           content_css: "css/content.css",
           toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | save | table | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons charmap code | hr paste pagebreak searchreplace spellchecker template visualblocks insertdatetime", 
           style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
            ]
         });
    </script>
```

and in my html page :

```
    <div class="page-content">
        <form action="somewhere" method="post" role="form">
            Title:<br/> <input type="text" name="title" style="width:100%"/><br/> <br /> Your Text:<br/>
            <textarea name="content" class="tinymce" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
            <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the fullpage plugin :)

Comment: If you need to get the `body` tag take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195615/get-contents-of-body-body-within-a-string

Comment: find   **fullpage**  inside of    **plugins** : [.....]    and remove.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker"
    ],
```

remove the fullpage plugin from script

Comment: My customer is complaining about it and I don't see the fullpage plugin here. This is all I use: plugins : "table,inlinepopups". Any tip?

Comment: @PauloPedroso if you see the plugins: [...] section, by removing the fullpage you will be able to get that .

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, if I recall, there are some kind of controls where you say you wanna add newline and by setting that to false I was able to get that done. Unfortunately the project is with another company already and I don't have access to the code to look at how I managed it. but I do remember there was no fullpage plugin in its section.

Comment: @PauloPedroso that's ok, maybe I can help you in some other new stuffs in the future ... anyways Good Luck

Comment: Thanks @mehdi! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Solve my probelm!

Answer (score 2):

This might be simpler:

```
b = "<body>";
be = "</body>";
t = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
t = t.substring((t.indexOf(b) + b.length), (t.indexOf(be)-1)) //need substring() (including comment b/c can't make edit under 6 chars)
```

The "t" value can be then actively placed in the "textarea" value (not setContent()) of the tinymce editor, before sending.

Hope that helps..

Comment: this should be accepted answer. Presumably one has the fullpage plugin because one wants to include the functionality, removing it is like amputating a leg for an ingrown toenail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions for getting body content and character count

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yerheo1L/)

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "mybutton",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            icon: 'image',
            onclick: function(e) {
                console.log(e.target);
                console.log(editor.getContent());
               var utf8length = 0;
               var string = editor.getContent();
                 for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
        if (c < 128) {
            utf8length++;
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utf8length = utf8length+2;
        }
        else {
            utf8length = utf8length+3;
        }
    }
    console.log(utf8length);
    var str = editor.getContent();
      var m = encodeURIComponent(str).match(/%[89ABab]/g);
   console.log(editor.getContent());
    console.log(str.length + (m ? m.length : 0));


                  }
        });
    }});
```