# Using Javascript and Regular expression to get content inside the html body

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract body contents using regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628374/how-to-extract-body-contents-using-regexp)

I have response text which is having a full page content like html,head,body.I want only the content inside the body.How to achieve this using regx.please help to achieve this.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions. Use the DOM. Regular expressions aren't well-suited to parsing HTML.

Answer (score 6):

A DOM parser is the most reliable method for extracting data like this, but a regex can do a pretty decent job if the HTML is sane. (i.e. the text: `<body` or: `</body` does not occur inside comments, scripts, stylesheets, CDATA sections or attribute values. And the BODY element start tag attributes do not contain the: `>` character.) This regex captures the contents of the first innermost BODY element (should only ever be one):

```
var bodytext = '';
var m = text.match(/<body[^>]*>([^<]*(?:(?!<\/?body)<[^<]*)*)<\/body\s*>/i);
if (m) bodytext = m[1];
```

It implements Jeffrey Friedl's *"Unrolling-the-Loop"* efficiency technique so is quite fast.